# Equivalence of $-\frac {\ln t}{\sqrt{t-t^2}} $ in the neighbourhood of one

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Good afternoon,

> I'm trying to find the equivalent of $f:t\to-\dfrac {\ln t}{\sqrt{t-t^2}} $ in the neighbourhood of one .

I have got a problem with the sign of my result.

$f(t)=-\dfrac {\ln t}{\sqrt{t-t^2}} $

Let $u:=1-t$

$f(u)=-\dfrac {\ln (1-u)}{\sqrt{u-u^2}}=-\dfrac {\ln (1-u)}{\sqrt{u}\sqrt{1-u}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{u}}{\sqrt{1-u}}\cdot\dfrac{\ln (1-u)}{-u}\underset{0}{\sim}\sqrt{u}\cdot(-u)=-u^{3/2}$

Thus $f(t)\underset{1^-}{\sim}\color {red}-(1-t)^{3/2}$

My problem is the minus sign highlighted above in red

Since $t\in \mathcal{D}_f=(0,1)\implies f(t)>0$ but $-(1-t)^{3/2}<0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You lost the initial $-$ sign.

This being said, the computation can be simpler with *Taylor's formula* at order $1$ and standard equivalents:

- $\ln(1-u)\sim_0-u$
- $\dfrac1{\sqrt{1-u}}=1-\frac12(-u)+o(u)=1+\frac12u+o(u)\sim_0 1$.

So we obtain
$$=-\frac {\ln (1-u)}{\sqrt{u-u^2}}\sim_0\frac u{\sqrt u\cdot1}=\sqrt u.$$

Comment: I just come to find my mistake, $$\dfrac{\ln (1-u)}{-u} \sim 1$$, thanks